# Parse query only working from one device

Tags: android, parse-platform, collaboration

I am currently developping an app android app with a friend and we are using Back4App's parse as a backend.

We're syncing our version with BitBucket and haven't encountered major problems until now.

Our app bassically needs to get objects from a Parse Class and show them in a list.

The thing is that the following code used to collect that data from Parse only works on my device and I have no idea why.

```
ParseQuery<Object> q = ParseQuery.getQuery("Object");
    q.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Object> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
               // Objects added in the list here
            }
        }
    });
```

The code is working like charm on my device but it isn't on anything else and I have no idea why.

I also checked that the problem wasn't connecting to Parse with his device because authentification through the app works very well on everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out I haven't thought about checking ACL in my Parse Class and only my account could access the test values

Sorry if I wasted someone's time. That was my bad.

Comment: this was a great question and answer, thanks @archipel!   How have you found back4app to be working with Unity??

Comment: @JoeBlow I haven't tried using back4app with Unity but I'm sure it works just fine since it is based on parse

Comment: hi @archipel, I beg your pardon I didn't notice the Android tag. Thanks for the info.  Have you found with Android, that back4app seems to work the same as Parse?  Haven't run in to any troubles?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, from what I understood it is Parse but hosted by someone else. I find it to be really simple to start with and I haven't had any major issues for now.